$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\ln\left(\frac{p^{z_n}(1-p)^{1-z_n}}{{q^{z_n}(1-q)^{1-z_n}}}\right)$ approximates $D_{KL}(\text{Bern}(p)||\text{Bern}(q))$?
Let $Z_n\overset{iid}{\sim}\text{Bernoulli}(p)$ for some $p\in[0,1]$. Fix some $q\in[0,1]$, where $q$ may $-$ or may not $-$ be equal to $p$.
Fix some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and fix some sequence of realizations $(z_1,...,z_N)\in\{0,1\}^N$. I am reading a source (omitted, since it contains a lot of distracting details) that says that for "large" values of $N$,
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\ln\left(\frac{p^{z_n}(1-p)^{1-z_n}}{{q^{z_n}(1-q)^{1-z_n}}}\right)
$$
is "asymptotically equal to" $p\ln\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)+(1-p)\ln\left(\frac{1-p}{1-q}\right)$, which is the Kullback–Leibler Divergence from $\text{Bernoulli}(q)$ to $\text{Bernoulli}(p)$. No elaboration was provided on what is precisely meant by "asymptotically equal to." That is essentially half of my question. (The other half is how the statement is proven; no details/references were provided there, too.)
If anyone knows the complete, formal statement of what I described above (and how it is proven) I would very much appreciate your help.

Statements like "asymptotically equal to" can have many different technical meanings, depending on context, so it's not really possible to say exactly what they meant without you telling us the source. Nevertheless, we can see that there are basic senses in which this statement is true, e.g., the limit of this sequence as $N$ diverges is the KL divergence almost surely. To see this, use the rules of logarithms to write the expression as $\sum z_n \cdot \textrm{something} + (1-z_n)\cdot \textrm{something},$ and apply the law of large numbers.

Don't know if this helps but for any fixed $N>0$, one can show that the mean value is $p\ln\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)+(1-p)\ln\left(\frac{1-p}{1-q}\right)$.

Your random variable can be written as $\frac{(N-X) \log \left(\frac{1-p}{1-q}\right)}{N}+\frac{X \log \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)}{N}$ where $X\sim Binomial(N, p)$.
